# Is it possible to increase char array while using it, WITHOUT malloc?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have a char array, we know that that a char size is 1 byte. Now I have to collect some char -> getchar() of course and simultaneously increase the array by 1 byte (without malloc, only library: stdio.h)

My suggestion would be, pointing to the array and somehow increase that array by 1 till there are no more chars to get OR you run out of Memory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to increase `char` array while using it, WITHOUT `malloc`?

**Quick answer:** No it is not possible to increase the size of an array without reallocating it.

**Fun answer:** Don't use `malloc()`, use `realloc()`.

**Long answer:**

If the `char` array has static or automatic storage class, it is most likely impossible to increase its size at runtime because keeping it at the same address that would require objects that are present at higher addresses to be moved or reallocated elsewhere.

If the array was obtained by `malloc`, it might be possible to extend its size if no other objects have been allocated after it in memory. Indeed `realloc()` to a larger size might return the same address. The problem is it is impossible to predict and if `realloc` returns a different address, the current space has been freed so pointers to it are now invalid.

The efficient way to proceed with this reallocation is to increase the size geometrically, by a factor at a time, 2x, 1.5x, 1.625x ... to minimize the number of reallocations and keep linear time as the size of the array grows linearly. You would a different variable for the allocated size of the array and the number of characters that you have stored into it.

Here is an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *a = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (count >= size) {
            /* reallocate the buffer to 1.5x size */
            size_t newsize = size + size / 2 + 16;
            char *new_a = realloc(a, new_size);
            if (new_a == NULL) {
                fprintf("out of memory for %zu bytes\n", new_size);
                free(a);
                return 1;
            }
            a = new_a;
            size = new_size;
        }
        a[count++] = c;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        putchar(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to increase char array while using it, WITHOUT malloc?

No.

You cannot increase the size of a *fixed* size array.

For that you need [realloc()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) from `<stdlib.h`>, which it seems you are not "allowed" to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create space for the string without using dynamic memory allocation(malloc...). You can use a static array or an array with automatic storage duration, you need to specify a maximum amount, you might never reach. But always check against it.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 0x10000
```

Static

```
static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Or automatic (You need to ensure BUFFER_SIZE is smaller than the stack size)

```
int main() {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ...
};
```

There are also optimizations done by the operating system. It might lazily allocate the whole (static/automatic) buffer, so that only the used part is in the physical memory. (This also applies to the dynamic memory allocation functions.) I found out that calloc (for big chunks) just allocates the virtual memory for the program; memory pages are cleared only, when they are accessed (probably through some interrupts raised by the cpu). I compared it to an allocation with malloc and memset. The memset does unnessecary work, if not all bytes/pages of the buffer are accessed by the program.

**If you cannot allocate a buffer with malloc..., create a static/automatic array with enough size and let the operating system allocate it for you.** It does not occupy the same space in the binary, because it is just stored as a size.